# Sending loaded object to view and getting back changes from POST using Razor Pages

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

After performing a table query, loading up an object with properties, and sending it back to the view, I'd like to update some of the properties and post it back to the Azure table.

I have a model binding in my Razor Page cs file as follows:

```
[BindProperty]
public TenantSettingsModel Settings { get; set; }
```

In my `OnGetAsync` method I load up the `Settings` object as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    Settings = _azureTableConn.GetTenantSettings(passSomeValue);
    return Page();
}
```

At this stage I can see `Settings` is loaded with the properties to return to the view. I'm only picking out a couple of the properties to display in a form and I'd like to post back those two changes (if any) along with the other unchanged properties to the `OnPostAsync` method as follows and render a view:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var response = _azureTableconn.SetTenantSettings(Settings);
    return Page();
}
```

When I inspect the `Settings` object it has the two form properties but the others are null. I could simply set them manually but it seems like a waste.

Is it possible to send an object with pre-defined properties, then change two of them in a form, but retain the unchanged properties when it comes back from the view?

My only other thought is to create hidden form elements to hold the [in]bound properties from the model but if I have to do this I'm better off setting it in my `OnPostAsync` method I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen your pages or code but I just made some postings to CodeProject that may help. It appears you may need to use a form element in your .cshtml file.  Your [BindProperty] attribute would make your TenantSettingsModel values available to the elements in your UI.  You might look at ([ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Using EntityFramework Core with Enums as Strings - Part II](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264283/ASP-NET-Core-Razor-Pages-Using-EntityFramework-C-2))

I am using Entity Framework Core here.

In one example I edit a Customer object on a Razor page, Edit.cshtml ([Note: I do use a hidden input to pass the Customer.CustomerId to the PostAsync() method]):

```
@page
@model QuantumWeb.Pages.Customers.EditModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<h4>Customer</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Customer.CustomerId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Customer.CustomerName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Customer.CustomerName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Customer.CustomerName"
                    class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Customer.CustomerContact"
                    class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Customer.CustomerContact" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Customer.CustomerContact"
                    class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Customer.CustomerPhone"
                    class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Customer.CustomerPhone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Customer.CustomerPhone"
                    class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Customer.CustomerEmail"
                    class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Customer.CustomerEmail" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Customer.CustomerEmail"
                    class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

The "code-behind", Edit.cshtml.cs:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using QuantumWeb.Data;
using QuantumWeb.Model;

namespace QuantumWeb.Pages.Customers
{
    public class EditModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly QuantumDbContext _context;

        public EditModel(QuantumDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        } // end public EditModel(QuantumDbContext context)

        [BindProperty]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            } // endif (id == null)

            Customer =
                await _context.Customers
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CustomerId == id);

            if (Customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            } // endif (Customer == null)
            return Page();
        } // end public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            } // endif (!ModelState.IsValid)

            _context.Attach(Customer).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            } // end try
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!CustomerExists(Customer.CustomerId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                } // endif (!CustomerExists(Customer.CustomerId))
            } // end catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        } // end public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()

        private bool CustomerExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Customers.Any(e => e.CustomerId == id);
        } // end private bool CustomerExists(int id)

    } // end public class EditModel : PageModel

} // end namespace QuantumWeb.Pages.Customers
```

I hope this helps.

I have other parts in my CodeProject post (Parts III & IV) that use Entity Framework eager loading to load related data in the GET. ( [ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Using EntityFramework Core with Enums as Strings - Part III and [ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Using EntityFramework Core with Enums as Strings - Part IV](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264741/ASP-NET-Core-Razor-Pages-Using-EntityFramework-C-2))

In Part IV I have a page, CustomerProjectSkillAssign.cshtml:

```
@page "{id:int?}"
@model QuantumWeb.Pages.Customers.CustomerProjectSkillAssignModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Customer Project Skill Assignment";
}

<h2>Customer Project Skill Assignment</h2>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Project.ProjectId)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Project.ProjectId)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Project.ProjectName)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Project.ProjectName)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer.CustomerId)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Customer.CustomerId)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer.CustomerName)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Customer.CustomerName)
    </dd>
</dl>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Project.ProjectId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SkillTitle.SkillCode" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="SkillTitle.SkillCode" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.SkillCode"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <a asp-page="./CustomerProjectSkills" asp-route-id="Project.ProjectId">Project Skills</a> |
                <input type="submit" value="Assign" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice I have only one hidden control that has the Project.ProjectId
The CustomerProjectSkillAssign.cshtml.cs:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using QuantumWeb.Data;
using QuantumWeb.Model;

namespace QuantumWeb.Pages.Customers
{
    public class CustomerProjectSkillAssignModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly QuantumDbContext _context;

        public CustomerProjectSkillAssignModel(QuantumDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        } // end public CustomerProjectSkillAssignModel(QuantumDbContext context)


        [BindProperty]
        public Project Project { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public SkillTitle SkillTitle { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            } // endif (id == null)

            Project = await _context.Projects
                .Include(p => p.Customer)
                .Include(p => p.ProjectSkills)
                    .ThenInclude(ps => ps.SkillTitle)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProjectId == id);

            if (Project == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            } // endif (Project == null)

            Customer = Project.Customer;

            ViewData["SkillCode"] = new SelectList(_context.SkillTitles, "SkillCode", "Title");

            return Page();
        }// end public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(int? id)

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            } // endif (!ModelState.IsValid)

            ProjectSkill projectSkill = new ProjectSkill()
            {
                ProjectId = Project.ProjectId,
                SkillCode = SkillTitle.SkillCode
            };

            _context.ProjectSkills.Add(projectSkill);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./CustomerProjectSkills", new { id = Project.ProjectId });
        } // end public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()

    } // end public class CustomerProjectSkillAssignModel : PageModel

} // end namespace QuantumWeb.Pages.Customers
```

The eager loading retrieves the Project object and its Customer object and its collection of ProjectSkills.  Each ProjectSkill has a SkillTitle.  In addition I load a collection of available SkillTitle objects into a select/dropdown.  The selected item is passed to OnPostAsync() via the form.  However, there is only one hidden control to indicate the target Project.

Comment: Ya it looks like if you give the page a hidden property for each inbound item, you can pull them out in the `post` method by accessing the object by name.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar challenge and not sure if my approach is right. Instead of displaying the data (to be edited) in DIV, I'm displaying in a TABLE. I can understand how the hidden property is updating the row. In my case I am displaying multiple rows on the Edit page, but unable to update the database for only rows which have updates.

My view page is like this

```
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>        
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fields[0].Name) </th>
                <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fields[0].Value) </th>
                <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fields[0].Confidence) </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Fields)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td> <input type="hidden" asp-for=@item.ID /> </td>
                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) </td>
                    <td contenteditable='true'> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value) </td>
                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Confidence) </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And the code behind is this. The Fields is showing 0 in the OnPostAsync method.

```
[BindProperty]
    public IList<FieldInfo> Fields { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        Fields = await _context.FieldInfo.Where(m => m.GUID == id).ToListAsync();

        if (Fields == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        foreach (var p in Fields) // In this approach Fields shows as count=0
        {
            _context.Attach(p.Value).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        _context.Attach(Fields).State = EntityState.Modified; // In this approach Exception: The entity type 'List<FieldInfo>' was not found.

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();            
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```